# How to integrate BottomNavigation with NavigationDrawer using material library

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

This is my AppBottomNavigationController.swift file

```
import UIKit
import Material

class AppBottomNavigationController: BottomNavigationController {


    open override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        prepareTabBar()

    }

    private func prepareTabBar() {
        tabBar.depthPreset = .none
        tabBar.dividerColor = UIColor.init(red: 27/255, green: 15/255, blue: 24/255, alpha: 1.0)
        tabBar.backgroundColor  = UIColor.init(red: 27/255, green: 15/255, blue: 24/255, alpha: 1.0)
        //tabBar.barTintColor = Color.blue
    }
}
```

This is my AppNavigationDrawerController.swift file

```
import UIKit
import Material

class AppNavigationDrawerController: NavigationDrawerController {
    open override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        delegate = self
        Application.statusBarStyle = .default
    }
}

extension AppNavigationDrawerController: NavigationDrawerControllerDelegate {
    func navigationDrawerController(navigationDrawerController: NavigationDrawerController, willOpen position: NavigationDrawerPosition) {
        print("navigationDrawerController willOpen")
    }

    func navigationDrawerController(navigationDrawerController: NavigationDrawerController, didOpen position: NavigationDrawerPosition) {
        print("navigationDrawerController didOpen")
    }

    func navigationDrawerController(navigationDrawerController: NavigationDrawerController, willClose position: NavigationDrawerPosition) {
        print("navigationDrawerController willClose")
    }

    func navigationDrawerController(navigationDrawerController: NavigationDrawerController, didClose position: NavigationDrawerPosition) {
        print("navigationDrawerController didClose")
    }

    func navigationDrawerController(navigationDrawerController: NavigationDrawerController, didBeginPanAt point: CGPoint, position: NavigationDrawerPosition) {
        print("navigationDrawerController didBeginPanAt: ", point, "with position:", .left == position ? "Left" : "Right")
    }

    func navigationDrawerController(navigationDrawerController: NavigationDrawerController, didChangePanAt point: CGPoint, position: NavigationDrawerPosition) {
        print("navigationDrawerController didChangePanAt: ", point, "with position:", .left == position ? "Left" : "Right")
    }

    func navigationDrawerController(navigationDrawerController: NavigationDrawerController, didEndPanAt point: CGPoint, position: NavigationDrawerPosition) {
        print("navigationDrawerController didEndPanAt: ", point, "with position:", .left == position ? "Left" : "Right")
    }

    func navigationDrawerController(navigationDrawerController: NavigationDrawerController, didTapAt point: CGPoint, position: NavigationDrawerPosition) {
        print("navigationDrawerController didTapAt: ", point, "with position:", .left == position ? "Left" : "Right")
    }

    func navigationDrawerController(navigationDrawerController: NavigationDrawerController, statusBar isHidden: Bool) {
        print("navigationDrawerController statusBar is hidden:", isHidden ? "Yes" : "No")
    }
}
```

I was trying to implement tab bar navigation with side bar navigation. I have tried a lot but I can not make it out. Please help me out
Thanks in advance